# "Jos" name in itself or a short form of "Joseph" or "Johannes"?

Tags: palaeography, marriage-records, austria, parish-register

I have here this [German-Latin marriage record from Austria about the marriage between Angelus Constantin and Catharina Werckin on the 11th April, 1780](http://data.matricula-online.eu/de/oesterreich/wien/01-st-stephan/02-073/?pg=360) (last entry on page):

[image: Cath Werkin zoom]

The father of Catharina Werckin is listed as Jos Werk. Is his first name really "Jos" or is it possibly a short form of Joseph or Johannes?

[image: Jos zoom]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have seen in baptism/marriage/death entries Jos. is a common abbreviation of Joseph. John (Johann, in Latin [Joannes/Ioannes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ioannes#Latin)) would have been abbreviated as Joan., Joa. or Joh. See e.g. [that entry](http://data.matricula-online.eu/de/oesterreich/gurk/pusarnitz/P12_004-1/?pg=450), first line, last column:

> coop. Joa. Ant. Mogetini p. t.

meaning interim chaplain John Anthony [Joannes Antonius] Mogetini.